# Config all log levels by using spring boot actuator

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am using spring boot actuator to config the log levels (https://www.programmersought.com/article/85717269729/). I can config the specific class to different log levels, but when I try to config the log levels for all ( `curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "TRACE"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/ROOT`), I receive the below error, any idea?

```
21-06-21 16:25:18.638 DEBUG 53564 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1cc6be3b:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@18f9297b:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55470]], Read from buffer: [0]
2021-06-21 16:25:18.643 DEBUG 53564 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1345) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1255) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:799) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_272]

2021-06-21 16:25:18.644 DEBUG 53564 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
```

Answer (score 0):

The logging isn't reporting an error. It's a debug message about an implementation detail of Tomcat that is entirely normal. It is only being output as your `POST` request with curl has successfully changed the log level for the `ROOT` logger.

Comment: Thanks you. But this message is always printing, and I cannot even see the log message which I want.